# Allow API to be used by external applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a Angular 8 + Asp.Core application and added JWT authentication on existing user database
I want to share one Api controller for outside access (PHP site),but not to all controllers.
How to create a second token and give it access only for a single controller?

A simple solution is to send a security key with request data and check if that key exists in database,but I don't know how secure it is

my current code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
.............
 var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<UserSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
}


[Authorize]
        public class OtherController : Controller
        {....
```

login controller:

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
         public class LoginController : Controller
                {
                    private readonly Entities db;
                    private readonly UserSettings appSettings;

                    public LoginController(Entities _db, IOptionsSnapshot<UserSettings> _appSettings)
                    {
                        db = _db;
                        appSettings = _appSettings.Value;

                    }

                    [Route("/api/login")]
                    [HttpPost]
                    public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginData logindata)
                    {
                        var user = db.HT_USERS
                          .SingleOrDefault(u => u.USERNAME == logindata.Username && 
        DecryptString128Bit(u.PASSW, "passwkey") == logindata.Password);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            return NotFound();
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
                            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                            {
                                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                                {
                                  new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier , user.ID.ToString())
                                }),
                                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                                new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                            };


                            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

                            return Ok(new
                            {
                                username = user.NAME,
                                token = tokenString
                            });

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: this is what authorisation attributes on your controllers/actions is for

Comment: [Authorize] is put on all controllers (except login)

Comment: ok well then you need to introduce the concept of roles. Make the "outside access" controller usable by one role (or roles). Make the other controllers usable by a different role (or roles). If a user connects using a token associated with a specific account, then the authorisation attribute will check whether the user has the right role to access that controller or not. The authorise attribute can be told the roles which it may allow.

Comment: too complicate for me,it is possible to create another token and to use it only for that controller?

Comment: why is it too complicated? If you don't understand, learn it. The feature is built into ASP.NET Identity, so it should be very well documented, and quite easy to use. Almost all IT systems use roles in their access technology - hopefully the general concept is familiar to you. Think of security groups in Windows (or Linux), for example.

Comment: Anyway I guess you could just authorise a single user (rather than a single role) to access a controller. The difficulty is how you stop that user from accessing other controllers, without having a blacklist. Roles is easier to maintain, and more flexible.